# Reassigning variables or returning new objects?

Tags: javascript, function, variable-assignment, object-literal, memory-efficient

I am working on a certain project in Processing JS in which I have a function to project points from 3D onto the screen using an isometric projection.

```
var xy = function(x, y, z) {
    return {
        x: 300 + cos(30) * x + cos(30 + 120) * z;
        y: 300 + sin(30) * x + sin(30 + 120) * z - y;
    };
};
```

To graph a point I would do

```
var p = xy(10, 20, 30); // 10, 20, and 30 being the x, y, and z values respectively
point(p.x, p.y);
```

This function gets called lots and lots of time for frame, so I want to be efficient. Once, someone told me that when I do

```
return {
    x: ...
    y: ...
};
```

it creates a new object in the memory each time the function gets called. He said to instead do the function like so

```
var p = {x:0,y:0};
var xy = function(x, y, z) {
    p.x = 300 + cos(30) * x + cos(30 + 120) * z;
    p.y = 300 + sin(30) * x + sin(30 + 120) * z - y;
};
```

and to graph a point do

```
xy(10, 20, 30);
point(p.x, p.y);
```

now thats all well and good if I'm conserving memory, but it worked without much lag when I was using the old method, but I think the new method with reassigning variables seemed to be more laggy and also Safari did not do the popup "This webpage is using significant memory. Closing it may improve the performance of your mac." but for the new method it did do "This webpage is using significant energy. Closing it may improve the performance of your mac." (JK it said it was using significant energy for both but I think it seemed laggier for the new method)

so basically my question is:

which is worse

```
var xy = function() {
    return {key:"val"};
};
// do it lots of times nonstop
setInterval(function(){for (var i=0; i<amillion; i++) {xy();}}, 1000);
```

or

```
var p = {key:"val"};
var xy = function() {
    p.key = "val";
};
// do it lots of times nonstop
setInterval(function(){for (var i=0; i<amillion; i++) {xy();}}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a test and it seems that they both work at the same speed and so yeah you're better off reassigning variables to save a few tidbits but you know what don't concern yourself too much with efficiency; easily readable code is more important.